# Replace a nodeset in XmlDocument with another XmlDocument file

Tags: c#, xml

I was wondering what would be the best way to do the following:

There are 2 XML files in a directory "Input.xml" and "Metadata.xml".

Input.xml:

```
<Root>
  <Header>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>Test</Name>
  </Header>
  <Body>
    <MetaDataSet>
        <ID>23568</ID>
        <Value>metadatavalue1</Value>
    </MetaDataSet>
  </Body>
</Root>
```

Metadata.xml:

```
<MetaDataSet>
   <metadatasetvalue>Test</metadatasetvalue>
   <Valid>true</Valid>
</MetaDataSet>
```

What I would like to do is to be able to replace the node set "MetaDataSet" of "Input.xml" with the entire content of the file "Metadata.xml".
So the resulting output would be:

```
<Root>
  <Header>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>Test</Name>
  </Header>
  <Body>
    <MetaDataSet>
        <metadatasetvalue>Test</metadatasetvalue>
        <Valid>true</Valid>
    </MetaDataSet>
  </Body>
</Root>
```

Is it possible in c# to replace a nodeset with an XmlDocument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the two Xml documents in two [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx) classes, call [SelectSingleNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.selectsinglenode(v=vs.110).aspx) and then replace the [InnerXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.innerxml(v=vs.110).aspx) of the found element with the [OuterXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.outerxml(v=vs.110).aspx) of the meta [DocumentElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.documentelement(v=vs.110).aspx), like so:

```
var i = @"
     <Root>
      <Header>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Name>Test</Name>
      </Header>
      <Body>
        <MetaDataSet>
            <ID>23568</ID>
            <Value>metadatavalue1</Value>
        </MetaDataSet>
      </Body>
    </Root>";

      var m = @"
      <MetaDataSet>
       <metadatasetvalue>Test</metadatasetvalue>
       <Valid>true</Valid>
    </MetaDataSet>
      ";
  var input2 = new XmlDocument();
  input2.Load(new StringReader(i));

  var meta2 = new XmlDocument();
  meta2.Load(new StringReader(m));

  var body2 = input2.DocumentElement["Body"]; 
  body2.InnerXml = meta2.DocumentElement.OuterXml;

  // helper to show the result
  sb = new StringBuilder();
  using(var xw = XmlWriter.Create(sb)) {
     input2.Save(xw);
  }
  sb.Dump("2");
```

If you are open to change to the [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) class you can use [ReplaceNodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.replacenodes(v=vs.110).aspx) on an element:

```
  var inDoc = XDocument.Parse(i);
  var metaDoc = XDocument.Parse(m);
  var body = inDoc.Root.Element("Body");

  body.ReplaceNodes(metaDoc.Root);

  // helper to show the result     
  var sb = new StringBuilder();
  using(var xw = XmlWriter.Create(sb)) 
  {
     inDoc.WriteTo(xw);
  }
  sb.Dump(); // LinqPad helper
```

Comment: I see you are kind of torn in between XmlDocument and its XPath approach on one side, and also XDocument/XElement on the other. You can actually use XPath in LINQ-to-XML - check my answer.

Comment: @Neolisk good observation.... fixed by using only DOM navigation in both options....

Answer (score 2):

It's also possible using [ReplaceWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.replacewith(v=vs.110).aspx) and [XPath with LINQ-to-XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/bb387057.aspx).

Assuming the same init as [in @rene's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27204344/897326) for variables `i` and `m`:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

var inDoc = XElement.Parse(i);
var metaDoc = XElement.Parse(m);
inDoc.XPathSelectElement("//Body/MetaDataSet").ReplaceWith(metaDoc);
```